# How to execute a batch file with chinese characters

Tags: windows, batch-file

Our automation test framework creates batch files as part of starting an application (.exe). In my case this application takes username and passwords as arguments. As part of one of the test cases, username is a chinese name. Test framework is creating batch file with correct chinese username but the application's UI is taking some junk values(with question marks and some other symbols) in the corresponding username field. So, authentication is failing.

I have searched and tried to use chcp codepage command  in the generated batch file, updated batch file with different values of code page numbers (1250,1252,1253,65001,..). But nothing worked. But When I use code page number 1250, one of the chinese character(first character among three) is received by application correctly but junk values for other characters.

Ex. content of batch file: xxx.exe -user "abc" -password "xyz"

How can I solve this problem, Not able to find solutions by searching internet.

Comment: just to clarify: not the name of the batch file is the problem, but something that is written in it?

Comment: @akira, Yes the problem is while executing the batch file. It is not the problem of name of batch file.

Comment: Would it help to save the batch file with a `.ps1` extension and let PowerShell launch xxx.exe?

Comment: @rojo Jan, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is 
CHCP 65001 
for utf8 or what ever page you use
-decas

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the "€" sign. The onyl way I've found was to change the font of the cmd console to one that recognized the the symbol. However, this only helped while calling the bat file from an already opened console with the changed font. Doubleclicking on the bat file didn't work because then the font was reset to system default. Finally I've fixed it by changing the default cdm font in the registry but I'm not sure whether this helps you. While I've selected a font that had any other latin char and also some special symbols like €, ö, ß etc, I'm not sure whether there is a font that contains chinese AND latin chars.

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose "ANSI" as encoding in your text editor.